# Prevent multiple EventListeners from clashing on focus with Vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm extending my existing navigation for accessibility, but having issues when hitting "Enter" on the keyboard whilst the target are focused. The eventlisteners for the search and/or navigation toggle fire when any other element is focused on, this could be any anchor or any focused element.

Mouse clicking the individual elements (and clicking out of form) functions the way it needs to. However, on focus THEN hitting "Enter" anywhere on the page, it fires off, if not the right one, both events. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
/* Search */

let searchToggle = document.querySelector('.search-toggle'),
  searchForm = document.querySelector('.search-form');

function searchClick(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  let toggled = searchToggle.contains(event.target);
  if (toggled) {
    searchForm.classList.add('show-search-form');
  } else if (!event.target.closest('.show-search-form')) {
    searchForm.classList.remove('show-search-form');
  }
}

function searchFocus(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    searchToggle.click();
  }
}

document.addEventListener('click', searchClick, false);
document.addEventListener('keyup', searchFocus, false);

/* Navigation */

let navToggle = document.querySelector('.toggle'),
  nav = document.querySelector('.nav');

navToggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
  nav.classList.toggle('toggle-menu');
});

function navFocus(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    navToggle.click();
  }
}

document.addEventListener('keyup', navFocus, false);
```

```css
*:focus-visible {
  outline: 5px solid #333333;
}

.search-form,
.nav {
  display: none;
}

.search-form.show-search-form {
  display: block;
}

.nav.toggle-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="search-toggle" tabindex="0">
  <span>Toggle Search</span>
</div>
<div class="search-form">
  <span>Test Form</span>
</div>

<div class="toggle" tabindex="0">
  <span>Toggle Menu</span>
</div>

<nav class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: An event listener on `document` will fire when the event happens anywhere. Why shouldn't it fire both listeners?

Comment: @Barmar It's not meant to but, I have no clue. I thought event.stopPropagation() would solve this.

Comment: I agree with Barmar. Start by adding more specificity to your event listeners.

Comment: Check the difference between `event.StopPropagation()` and `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`. I suspect you want the latter.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I have tried the latter, both in and outside the if statement, still no luck sadly.